# Plugin and dependency not found

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster, maven-plugin

i've created a project with Jhipster, when i open the project with IntelliJ i have these problems in pom.xml:

[pom.xml problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s2j6.png)

I tried maven clean/package/install, the first two run successfully but when i run maven install a test fails:

[test failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWyME.png)

I also tried to use plugin registry (in maven settings) and invalidate caches but still not work. In the end i tried different JDK but i have the same problems. Can someone help me please?
I use JDK 11.0.15, Node 16.15.1, Git 2.36.1 and i'm on windows 10.

Comment: Does maven fail only in IntelliJ or also from command prompt? Which version of JHipster (run `jhipster version` in your generated project)? Regarding failing test, do you have a file src/test/resources/i18n/messages_it.properties ?

Comment: Thanks for answering me.

Yes maven (mvn install) also fail from command prompt:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (verify) on project prova: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\fnocentini\Documents\prova\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.

Jhipster version is 7.8.1.

I have messages_en.properties

Comment: The test fails because you don't have messages_it.properties (the italian translation), message_en.properfties is the english transaltion. 7.8.1 is the latest version so I think that there is a bug and you should open an issue on github https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues with all details including output of `jhipster info` so that JHipster team can reproduce. The bug being that i18n mail tests fail for non english languages.

Comment: As a workaround you can create message_it.properties by copying message_en.proprties

Comment: Your problem looks very similar to one that was supposed to be fixed: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/17946

Comment: Creating message_it.properties seems to work (mvn install run successfully), but i still have those problems in pom.xml

Comment: "Problems in pom.xml" are related to IntelliJ and I have no idea what's wrong here, as long as build works in command prompt, it means it's not an issue with maven nor JHipster. As a side comment, please don't use images when reporting errors, copy/paste text and format it correctly, it's easier for readers and it's searchable.

Comment: I undesrstand, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in troubleshooting pom.xml i solved by updating the repository (on IntelliJ go file/settings/build, execution, deployment/build tools/maven/repositories both remote and local) and reloading all maven projects.